# Using sys.stdin for square roots or other input calculations

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a newbie and honestly I'm having issues understanding how to do the below problem using stdin. I have an idea of what stdin does with user input but I'm confused on the provided code in the bottom and where to put in the input code.

Write a program that squares an integer and prints the result.

*Test 1*

- Test Input: 5
- Expected Output: 25

*Test 2*

- Test Input: 25
- Expected Output: 625

Code Given to begin with:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    Testinput = int()
    
    print(line, end="")
```

Comment: If I want to input a number as a user in order to calculate the square root, how would I use sys.stdin? For example if I input 5 and have the code print back 25 and loop so that the answer gives me 625.

Comment: In your code, `line` is a variable that will contain each string in the input, one for each iteration

Comment: Please make sure you understand that "squaring" the number and getting the "square root" are different - in fact, opposite - operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for line in sys.stdin:
     print(int(line)*int(line))
```

Does exactly the job you need to do!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer It got the result I wanted. Could you elaborate like dissect what each input does? For example what int(line).

Comment: Do you have any kind of textbook, instructor, anything? Where did the problem statement come from? You should read the textbook, ask the instructor, etc. Stack Overflow is not a free tutoring service.

Comment: Happy to hear it helped. You can press the up arrow and the tick to confirm this helped you if you wish. 

`int(line)` converts the line (a string) that you typed to an int type. It them multiplies this by `int(line)` again. The same as squaring a number (multiplying it by itself). Then using `print` it prints out this line on your terminal.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I tried clicking the up arrow but it gave me the following message "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."